# Free Image database, behind website

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, mongodb, web

I am working on a University project.
I have developed a test harness, one of the features of the test harness is visual regression testing.

I am developing a basic website, as a means to displays these generated images programmatically.

My original idea was to use a mongodb database, however after some reading many people advise not using mongodb to store images.

I then tried to use google drive and drop box, however they do not facilitate permanent url's to the stored images. Or in the case of dropbox, these urls are random so not programmatic.

I need to find a way to store these images, programmatically store them using a nodeJS script, programmatically access them using JS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not store them as files on the file system?  Or in any other kind of database if you don't want to use Mongo?

Comment: @David The test harness is going to be used by a team of people, I want them all to have access to the data

Comment: Multiple users can have access to the same file system or the same database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon S3 for saving and retrieveing images with  permanent url's 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html